# How to change a value to another value in a list for a 3x3 table for diagonal rows etc. be 15. A while loop that stops if condition not true

Tags: python

I have written a python code and It's a 3x3 table. In this table, you can choose the different numbers of each row. After it will check if is wrong or right. I have done some thing with the code myself. Problem is I want it to be obviously 3 numbers and all the elif/if statements if are false to stop and show the right solution for the 3x3.

```
rad1=[]
rad2=[]
rad3=[]          
while len(rad1)<3:  
    första_rad=int(input("Vad är sifror i första rad (vänster till höger)?"))
    rad1.append(första_rad)

while len(rad2)<3:
    andra_rad=int(input("Vad är sifror i andra rad (vänster till höger)?"))
    rad2.append(andra_rad)

while len(rad3)<3: 
    tredje_rad=int(input("Vad är sifror i tredje rad (vänster till höger)?"))
    rad3.append(tredje_rad)

diagonal_vänster=rad1[0]+rad2[1]+rad3[2] 
diagonal_höger=rad1[2]+rad2[1]+rad3[0] 

#sum of column from left to right

column1=rad1[0]+rad2[0]+rad3[0]
column2=rad1[1]+rad2[1]+rad3[1]
column3=rad1[2]+rad2[2]+rad3[2]


print(rad1)
print(rad2)
print(rad3)

#here it controls everything
if sum(rad1)!=15:
    print("första raden är fel")
    while len(rad1)
elif sum(rad2)!=15:
    print("andra raden är fel")
elif sum(rad3) != 15:
    print("tredje raden är fel")
elif diagonal_höger != 15:
    print("Diagonalen i höger är fel")
elif diagonal_vänster != 15:
    print("Diagonalen i vänster är fel")
elif column1!= 15:
    print("Det är fel med vänster column")
elif column2!= 15:
    print("Det är fel med mitt column")
elif column3!= 15:
    print("Det är fel med höger column")
```

I tried some while loops and everything but it doesn't help. Plus I don't know how to solve the issue with it needs to be the length of the list 3 and the sum 15.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this to check it its a valid number and only then add it to the list:

```
while len(rad1)<3:
    första_rad=input("Vad är sifror i första rad (vänster till höger)?")
    if första_rad.isnumeric():
        rad1.append(int(första_rad))
    else:
        print("please enter a valid number")
```

If you dont want your code to stop after the first if youve to change the `elif` into `if`.

```
#here it controls everything
if sum(rad1)!=15:
    print("första raden är fel")
if sum(rad2)!=15:
    print("andra raden är fel")
if sum(rad3) != 15:
....
```

lycka till min vän.snälla rösta upp och prenumerera

Comment: Hej!
Jag behöver något för att det ska kunna jobba indefinitiv tills det kan hitta ett lösning som gör att alla är 15 hur skulle jag göra?

Comment: Haha sry i dont speak swedish :)